# Compare the variance of two unbiased estimators

Tags: statistics, descriptive-statistics

Two unbiased estimators of $Y_i\sim N(\beta x_i, \sigma^2)$ with $\sigma$ known are $\tilde\beta=\dfrac{S_{xy}}{S_{xx}}=\dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\overline x)Y_i}{\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\overline x)x_i}$ and $\tilde{\tilde\beta}=\dfrac{\overline Y}{\overline x}$. How can I show $\operatorname{Var}(\tilde B)\le \text{Var}(\tilde{\tilde\beta})$?

I have gotten as far as determining $\text{Var}(\tilde\beta)=\dfrac{\sigma^2}{\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\overline x)^2}=\dfrac{\sigma^2}{\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\overline x)x_i}$ and $\operatorname{Var}(\tilde{\tilde\beta})=\dfrac{\sigma^2}{n\cdot\overline x^2}=\dfrac{n\sigma^2}{\left(\sum_{i=1}^nx_i\right)^2}$ but am unsure how to make a proper comparison.

Comment: It appears that you're looking for unbiased estimators, not of something called $G(\beta x_i,\sigma),$ but of $\beta. \qquad$

Comment: What does the capital $G$ mean?

Comment: Where you wrote $\operatorname{Var}(\widetilde B \le \widetilde{\widetilde\beta}),$ I presume you meant $\operatorname{Var}(\widetilde B) \le \operatorname{Var} (\widetilde{\widetilde\beta}).$ You should write things like that more carefully. $\qquad$

Comment: ok, I'm guessing that $G$ means "Gaussian." $\qquad$

Comment: $$
\operatorname{var}\left( \widetilde\beta \right) =\frac{\operatorname{var}(S_{xy})}{S_{xx}^2} = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-\overline x)^2 \operatorname{var}(Y_i)}{\left(\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\overline x)x_i\right)^2}
$$

Comment: Yes, G is for Gaussian. I changed it to N and \sigma^2, perhaps that is more common?

Comment: In view of the fact that you have $\beta x_i$ rather than $\alpha + \beta x_i$ as the expected value of $Y_i,$ so that you're estimating only $\beta$ and not both $\alpha$ and $\beta,$ I wonder if you should be working with $$ \tilde\beta = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i Y_i}{ \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2}, $$ which is the least-squares estimator of $\beta$ when you have that model without $\alpha.$ In that case I might start by trying to show that $\operatorname{cov} \left(\tilde\beta, \tilde\beta - \tilde{\tilde\beta} \right) = 0. \qquad$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\newcommand{\v}{\operatorname{var}}\newcommand{\c}{\operatorname{cov}}$If you had $$Y_i \sim N(\alpha+ \beta x_i, \sigma^2) \tag 1$$ and the $Y$s are independent, then the least-squares estimator of $\beta$ is $$\widehat\beta = \dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \overline x)Y_i}{\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-\overline x)x_i}.$$ But you have $$Y_i\sim N(\beta x_i,\sigma^2).\tag 2$$ You didn't mention independence but I will assume that was intended. In this situation, the least-squares estimator of $\beta$ is
$$
\widehat\beta = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i Y_i}{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2}. \tag 3
$$
Under $(2),$ the random variable
$$
\tilde{\tilde\beta} = \frac{\overline Y}{\overline x} \tag 4
$$
is also an unbiased estimator of $\beta.$

I will take the question to be: How can we show that $\v\left( \widehat\beta \right) \le \v\left( \tilde{\tilde\beta} \right),$ with $\widehat\beta$ defined as in line $(3)$ above.
\begin{align}
& \v\left(\tilde{\tilde\beta}\right) \\[10pt] = {} & \v\left( \left( \widehat\beta \right) + \left( \tilde{\tilde\beta} - \widehat\beta \right) \right) \\[10pt]
= {} & \v\left( \widehat\beta \right) + \v\left( \tilde{\tilde\beta} - \widehat\beta \right) + 2\c\left( \widehat\beta, \left( \tilde{\tilde\beta} - \widehat\beta \right) \right) \\[10pt]
= {} & \v\left( \widehat\beta \right) + \v\left( \tilde{\tilde\beta} - \widehat\beta \right) + 0 \qquad \text{(See below for justification of this line.)} \\[10pt]
\ge {} & \v\left( \widehat\beta\right).
\end{align}
It remains to show that the covariance appearing above is zero.
\begin{align}
\c\left( \widehat\beta, \widehat\beta - \tilde{\tilde\beta} \right) & = \c\left( \frac{\sum_{j=1}^n x_j Y_j}{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2}, \frac{\sum_{k=1}^n x_k Y_k}{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2} - \frac{\overline Y}{\overline x} \right) \\[10pt]
& = \frac 1 {\left( \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 \right)^2} \sum_{\ell=1}^n x_\ell^2 \v(Y_\ell) - \frac 1 {\left( \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 \right) \overline x} \sum_{j=1}^n x_j\c(Y_j, \overline Y) \\
& \qquad \text{In the first sum on the line above,} \\
& \qquad \text{all terms in which $j\ne k$ have vanished.} \\[10pt]
& = \frac 1 {\left( \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 \right)^2} \sum_{\ell=1}^n x_\ell^2 \sigma^2 - \frac 1 {\left( \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 \right) \overline x} \sum_{j=1}^n x_j \frac{\sigma^2} n
\end{align}
and then trivial cancelations do the rest. Specifically, $\sigma^2$ is a common factor, and $\sum_{\ell=1}^n x_\ell^2$ cancels a sum of squares in the denominator, and then $\sum_{j=1}^n x_j/n$ cancels $\overline x$ in the denominator.

**NOTE:** All of the above can be proved with weaker assumptions, as follows:

- Suppose $\operatorname E(Y_i) = \beta x_i$ and $\v(Y_i)= \sigma^2,$ for $i=1,\ldots, n,$ but do not assume these are normally distributed;
- We may drop any assumption that the $Y_i - \operatorname E(Y_i)$ all have the same distribution;
- Suppose $\c(Y_j,Y_k) = 0$ for $j\ne k$ but do not assume independence.

Everything in the argument above still works.

Comment: Amazing. Thank-you.

Comment: @StanGuedes : I'm glad it helped. You might want to google the term "Gauss–Markov theorem". One could say a central lemma here is that in this kind of model, under these assumptions, the least-squares estimator is uncorrelated with every linear unbiased estimator of zero. $\qquad$